# Interesting open-source APIs (Java) for self-education?

Tags: java, api

Which is your top 3 open-source APIs (in Java) you recommend as an example of well-designed piece of art?
That would be code that you had pleasure to browse through and got some insights from it.
Any problem domain acceptable.

Emphasis here is on **educational/study quality of code, complexity level - intermediate to top**.

Thanks a lot for responses.

Comment: Nice question, but please make this community wiki. Otherwise it will be closed soon (subjective and argumentative).

Comment: Please make this a community wiki.  Edit the question, and there is a checkbox there you can check.  Community wiki usually indicates "no specific right answer, but a wide range of responses."

Comment: @Dean J & tangens: Thanks! I'm novice here.

Comment: +1 to all those who advised Spring.  Note that Spring is doing a lot of things in a way that will displease a great many Java programmer who drank the Sun/Gosling Java kool-aid.  For example Spring is both very high on "Java interface" and very low on "checked exceptions".  Take *that* all you concrete-implementation/single-inheritance-checked-exceptions-code-monkeys :)

Comment: no problems.  People were awfully rude to me about the community wiki thing at first until I figured it out.  Community wiki posts don't give you reputation, but get a *lot* more responses, since you're not looking for any one right answer.   Welcome!

Answer (score 7):

I think that [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) is a great place to start. Josh Bloch advised the development of a lot of it, and it's a very well done API. While Spring is great, it's a little hard to know where to start. A good introduction to google collections is "coding in the small with google collections" (I can't post the actual link because of stackoverflow spam filter).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I'm greedily seeking all of stuff from Josh :). I saw few videos of him on API design. One of the things he mentioned was also concurrency stuff appeared in 5th SDK.

Comment: +1 for google collections. really gud to starts with

Comment: one more -> http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: @TiNS, @Paul: I heard a rumour that that some staff of Josh developed in Google might have been proposed as part of future SDK? I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

1.Spring
2.Hibernate

Comment: thanks for comment. Rod Johnson made a good start :) for Spring. Regarding the Hibernate, I had some experience in digging into it.

Comment: + Apache Software Foundation and Eclipse Foundation Projects

Answer (score 3):

- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) - it's a very well written and designed framework. It's a hell of a big bit of software but if want an example of how to build in a modular manner you can't go to fair wrong looking at the spring code base

Answer (score 0):

The sources of the java libraries are well documented.

In my experience the most valuable works include the documentation of desgin decisions, if you see a nice API it would be very interessting what could be the alternatives to that. Unfortunatly this is mostly burried mailing-lists of a project.

Comment: Hi. My experience shows that only particular java packages are worth of attention. There is really nightmarish stuff at some of SDK places.

Comment: @Max even if I've been downvoted, seeing art will not    necessarily make an artist out of you, only experience and talent does. So you have the skill to evaluate good software, every body likes the features of JIT have look on it's sources, this will be an advanced nigthmare to you.

Comment: (it wasn't me to downvote, my aim here not to downvote, but explore other peoples' opinion. cheers for answer)

Comment: Seeing code art, analyzing and experimenting with it do make you a code artist. Proven in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not an external library - but the java.util.concurrent package is very nicely written. The code isn't simple, but it's very well thought out and, in my opinion, has been written brilliantly.